# WScript Exec fails with a 128 error code

Tags: git, vbscript, asp-classic

I am currently trying to execute Git commands on a repository on a server that I do not have direct access to, through a VBScript script. Basic commands like displaying the current branch or all remote branches work. But as soon as I try to switch or reset the branch it fails out with a 128 error code. Here is the code:

```
If LCase(Request.QueryString("mode")) = "switch" Then
      strShellResult = execShellScript("git -C C:\my-folder\my-repo checkout master")
      Response.End
End If

Function execShellScript(command)
     Dim strOutput
     Dim objShell, objExec

     Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     Set objExec = objShell.Exec("%comspec% /c "&shellComand)

     If objExec.Status > 1 Then
        strOutput = objExec.StdErr.ReadAll
     Else
        strOutput = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll
     End If

     Response.write "objExec.Status: "&objExec.Status&"<br>"
     Response.write "objExec.ProcessID: "&objExec.ProcessID&"<br>"
     Response.write "objExec.ExitCode: "&objExec.ExitCode&"<br>"
     Response.write "strOutput: "&strOutput&"<br>"

     Set objShell = Nothing
     Set objExec = Nothing

     execShellScript = strOutput
End Function
```

That's about all. Commands like `git -C C:\my-folder\my-repo status` or `git -C C:\my-folder\my-repo rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` work. The Error Code supposedly means that:

> There are no child processes to wait for.

But that does not really help me. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks for your help,

Nunu

Edit 1: Managed to get a specific error: fatal: unable to write new index file. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Looks like a permission problem when `git` is trying to create files somewhere with the limited rights of your web server worker process. Run `procmon` and keep an eye out for ACCESS DENIED results. Change the process identity for your .asp file or give appropriate file system permissions.

Comment: Ah you're right! Thanks!